# maven-failsafe-plugin is not executing my integration tests

Tags: maven, integration, testng, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

Bellow a part of my actual pom.
Testng tests for integration tests have been assigned a "integration" group in the @Test annotations.
To do little test I did not exclude the "integration" group during the test phase.

When building using for example mvn verify or mvn install the integration tests get executed in the test phase, but not the verify or integration-test phase. 
The number of tests run remains 0. Somehow they are not picked up. Anyone have an idea on what might be wrong?

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <skip>false</skip>
          <excludedGroups>unit</excludedGroups>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>verify</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <skip>false</skip>
          <excludedGroups>unit</excludedGroups>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <skip>false</skip>
      <excludedGroups>unit</excludedGroups>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

> Update: Adding TestNG as a dependency to the failsafe plugin does not
>   help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

maven-failsafe-plugin by default includes only files matching [following patterns](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes):

```
<includes>
 <include>**/IT*.java</include>
 <include>**/*IT.java</include>
 <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

How did you name your test class(es)?

Comment: Hi, that could be it. All my tests have a TEST suffix. I' ll give this a try. Could you tell me where this is documented?

Comment: See link used in my reply - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes